# Encountered an unexpected condition: Unspecified error on Apple Vision

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-vision

My code is pretty basic, so what did i do wrong?

```
func updateClassifications(for image: UIImage) {

    let orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(image.imageOrientation)
    guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image) 
    else { 
        fatalError("Unable to create \(CIImage.self) from \(image).") 
    }
    let request = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest()
    
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage, 
                                        orientation: orientation)
        do {
            try handler.perform([request])
            print(request.results!)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to perform classification.\n\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error that says :

```
"Failed to perform classification." 
"Encountered an unexpected condition: Unspecified error"
```

Comment: Code runs on my real device, with a system image. Did you run your code on real device or sim?

Comment: Remove localizedDescription you might get more info from the entire error

Comment: simulator, i used a simulator and i hardcode the picture

Comment: The entire error is still an unknown error, so I choose not to remove it. but if you want to see it, I'll update it

Comment: My guess, that sim is a problem since image processing happens on your mac resource, you need to test on a real device.

Comment: Use “print(error)” instead of the version with localized description

Answer (score 0):

### Real iOS device vs Xcode Simulator

Two problems are: you're not using type casting for `VNObservation` abstract superclass and you're running the app on a Simulator instead of a real iOS device.

Try the following code to make your app work:

```
import SwiftUI
import Vision

struct SomeImage: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, 
                                    width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, 
                                   height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        updateClassifications(imageView.image!)            
        return view
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: UIView, context: Context) { }
    
    func updateClassifications(_ image: UIImage) {    
        let orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(image.imageOrientation)
        guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image) else {
            fatalError("Unable to create \(CIImage.self) from \(image).")
        }
        let request = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest()
        
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage,
                                            orientation: orientation)
            do {
                try handler.perform([request])
                print(request.results! as [VNFaceObservation])
            } catch {
                print("Failed to perform classification.\n\(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SomeImage().ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

---

```
extension CGImagePropertyOrientation {
    init(_ orientation: UIImage.Orientation) {
        switch orientation {
            case .up: self = .up
            case .upMirrored: self = .upMirrored
            case .down: self = .down
            case .downMirrored: self = .downMirrored
            case .left: self = .left
            case .leftMirrored: self = .leftMirrored
            case .right: self = .right
            case .rightMirrored: self = .rightMirrored
            @unknown default: fatalError()
        }
    }
}
```

Result (target iOS 16.3):

```
//   [<VNFaceObservation: 0x102d4f280> 
//     8C6AD235-9C20-440F-8D0B-43B54B73F1CF   
//     VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequestRevision3 
//     confidence=0.839766 
//     boundingBox=[0.274275, 0.280211, 0.491281, 0.464752]]
```